# Explicit conversion confusion in C#

Tags: c#

When I am doing:

**(a)**

```
int fah1 = 0:

float fah_to_cel1 = (fah1 - 32) / 9 * 5;
```

The value of fah1 still remains -15 which is similar when I declare fah_to_cel1 as int.

But when I do:

**(b)**

```
int fah1 = 0;

float fah_to_cel1 = ((float)fah1 - 32) / 9 * 5;
```

Then I get fah_to_cel1 as -17.777777778 which is right.

Why there is a need to explicitly convert the *fah_to_cel1* to **float** to get the right answer?

Comment: use float literals not integer literals eg. `32f`

Comment: FYI your question is unrelated to unity3d and game development

Comment: Besides first comment by @RandRandom, you could also try `float fah1 = 0f;`

Comment: `-32 / 9 = -3`, `-3 * 5 = -15`.  This is due to integer math.

Comment: Perhaps you are accustomed to Python where "/" always produces a float result.  In C/C++/C#, using the `/` operator on integers returns an integer.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts for making me understand it.